# unexpected illegal token changing multiple background in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('.rightArrow').click(function(){
            $('body').css({
                'background':
                'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)),
                 url("../img/change1.png") no-repeat center center fixed'
            });
        });
```

I did it with css but I got error in setting it using jquery. Is this even possible? or I should split them out, like only changing the background-image? since the overlay will be there for all images.

Comment: You need to use [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method of jquery in order to change the properties of the background.

Comment: @kidA updated my code but still got errors.

Comment: If your code is as it is written here there's the multi-line string problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript which could result in a syntax error. Or is that just SO formatting? Other than this it looks okay

Comment: You should set background value in single line

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a new line in the middle of a JavaScript string without escaping it. The new line character is the illegal token.

It should be:

```
'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)), url("../img/change1.png") no-repeat center center fixed'
```

or

```
'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)),\
url("../img/change1.png") no-repeat center center fixed'
```